# Liberated beings after Mahakalpa

Tags: brahma, kalpa, vaikuntha, samsara, varaha-purana

Do the liberated beings after Mahakalpa are again thrown into Samsara ?

Is the liberated stage after Moksha only for 1 kalpa ? If moksha is really permanent ?

[image: Here after doing the dwadshi fast followed by ekadashi the man went to Vaikuntha for 1 kalpa , after which he was reborn . This is from Varha Puran (Motilal Banarsidas Edition]

In the above picture it also says he went to Vaikuntha for 1 kalpa ( Varaha Puran { Motilal Banarsidas Edition} )

In the Kathopanishad bhashya for 2.3.16 Shankara cites a Vishnu purana verse:

तया नाड्या ऊर्ध्वम् उपरि आयन् गच्छन् आदित्यद्वारेण अमृतत्वम् अमरणधर्मत्वमापेक्षिकम्  ‘आभूतसम्प्लवं स्थानममृतत्वं हि भाष्येत’ (वि.पु. २.८.९७) इति स्मृतेः । ब्रह्मणा वा सह कालान्तरेण मुख्यममृतत्वमेति भुक्त्वा भोगाननुपमान्ब्रह्मलोकगतान् । विष्वङ् नानागतयः अन्या नाड्यः उत्क्रमणे उत्क्रमणनिमित्तं भवन्ति संसारप्रतिपत्त्यर्था एव भवन्तीत्यर्थः ॥

**which says: ‘Eternality’ means that state/position that will exist till the dissolution takes place.**

So is the same case with moksha . What happens after Mahakalpa ?

Can anyone clear this doubt

Comment: No , it doesn't .

Comment: Please anyone answer this